# Type directory into firefox save/open dialogue location bar?

Tags: linux, firefox, file-location, save-as

Is there a way to make the firefox open/save dialogues allow typing in the location bar?

Here is the [equivalent question for nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13645/typing-location-path-instead-of-clicking-directory-buttons-in-the-file-picker-di). Those solutions do not work for firefox.

Edit: I'm using firefox on linux, so it uses the GTK dialogue, which looks like this:

[image: firefox save as dialogue]

Comment: Hope you are searching for an option to specify a path when you open or save any downloads that is done in firefox. If this is the option you are looking for, then please follow the steps to enable the settings and enter your path by typing it. In Firefox, Settings/Options > in the 'General' tab > select "Always ask me where to save files" > click Ok. Now you should able to enter your desired path by typing. Hope this helps.

Comment: @vembutech: Already set. Sorry, I should have specified I'm on linux, because this problem doesn't exist in Windows. Edited into question.